# setMinimal equivalent in QRegularExpression

Tags: qt5, qt6, qregexp, qregularexpression

I am porting some Qt5 code to Qt6, which requires switching [QRegExp](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qregexp.html) to [QRegularExpression](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qregularexpression.html). The Qt5 code uses the [setMinimal(bool minimal)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qregexp.html#setMinimal) method of QRegExp. Is there an equivalent PatternOption in Qt6?

I see a [QRegularExpression::InvertedGreedinessOption](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qregularexpression.html#PatternOption-enum) PatternOption, but I don't really understand if this is equivalent.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] demonstrating the required behaviour.  As per the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qregularexpression.html#details) `QRegularExpression` employs the Perl regular expression syntax outlined by [pcrepattern](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pcrepattern.3.html).  If you want all quantifiers to behave in a minimal/non-greedy manner then it might be best to do so explicitly using the `?` qualifier.

Answer (score 0):

From Qt6 documentation, [Minimal matching](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtcore-changes-qt6.html#minimal-matching) says:

> [QRegExp::setMinimal()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qregexp.html#setMinimal) implemented minimal matching by simply reversing the greediness of the quantifiers ([QRegExp](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qregexp.html) did not support lazy quantifiers, like *?, +?, etc.). [QRegularExpression](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qregularexpression.html) instead does support greedy, lazy, and possessive quantifiers.
>
> The [QRegularExpression::InvertedGreedinessOption](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qregularexpression.html#PatternOption-enum) pattern option can be useful to emulate the effects of [QRegExp::setMinimal()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qregexp.html#setMinimal): if enabled, it inverts the greediness of quantifiers (greedy ones become lazy and vice versa).